# How does MongoDB compare to RDBMS and what are some structural benefits?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb

MongoDB is this great database I hear about. I'd like to evaluate its performance in typical scenarios relatively to traditional MySQL or SQL Server backends.

Assuming I would like to store data about employees in many company divisions:

In MySQL we would store a table containing divisions, and another containing employees and then link them.

In MongoDB, if we used a design where we have a document for each division containing employees within it, how would this scale with many employees? Is this an efficient structure for a database? Does MongoDB offer benefits performance-wise (I love that we can store bits of data without a traditional column)?

Comment: Mongodb is free, so just install it and test it in your scenario.

Comment: This is well covered in their documentation. They are very specific about answering pretty much these questions.  You spent more effort writing this than it would have reading their intro pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at some real world deployments - this can give you some idea.

random links:

- highscalability.com has [plenty of articles/links to presentations](http://highscalability.com/display/Search?moduleId=4876569&searchQuery=mongodb) mentioning it.
- [presentations on sliderhare](http://www.slideshare.net/search/slideshow?searchfrom=header&q=mongodb) mention it too.
- on scribd [too](http://www.scribd.com/search?query=mongodb).